# pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.10

In my SSH log

- /var/log/auth.log

I have the following 2 rows (which are repeated every hour):

> ...
>   **Jan 22 03:28:01 mam CRON[15934]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
>
>   Jan 22 03:28:01 mam CRON[15934]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root**
>   Jan 22 04:28:01 mam CRON[15943]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
>   Jan 22 04:28:01 mam CRON[15943]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
>   ...

This looks like a CRON job but when I check them for user root I get this:

- root@mam:~# crontab -l
  **no crontab for root**

Any suggestions regarding the cause and how to fix it?

Thanks, Udo

**Update** (based on the input from **grawity**):

I checked

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
28 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
56 23    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
8 23    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
13 23    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Looks that command

- cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly

is run hourly (at minute 28...) and executes what is in directory

- /etc/cron.hourly/

But this directory is empty:

> root@mam:/# ls -al /etc/cron.hourly/
>   total 12
>   drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 2010-10-12 16:26 .
>   drwxr-xr-x 67 root root 4096 2011-01-22 16:15 ..
>   -rw-r--r--  1 root root  102 2010-08-24 20:45 .placeholder

Comment: It doesn't matter if the /etc/cron.hourly directory is empty. Cron still execute (and use PAM) this job "cd / && run-parts...".

Comment: Please don't cross post questions to multiple Stackexchange sites.

Comment: somebody migrated the question which then was immediately closed as duplicate of this original question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu uses vixie-cron, which, in addition to `/var/spool/cron`, also looks in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*`.

---

`<Edit>` According to your update, you have four cronjobs in `/etc/crontab`. They are being run by `cron` on their specified times, and that's what causes the syslog messages.

**`cron` itself does not know anything about `/etc/cron.hourly/`, it just runs `run-parts`,** which handles said directory. As far as `cron` is concerned, the *`cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly`* job is exactly like another job, scheduled to run hourly. It is *not* magically skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Look /etc/cron.d or use find:

```
#find /etc/ -type f -exec grep -E "^28[ \t]" {} \; -print
```